# Is it possible to install an app through normal Samsung recovery?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, installation, apk

I was trying to install an app through recovery by flashing apk in flashable zip but it is not working.

It is showing an error.

What should I do?

Comment: Usually ZIP files only contain system updates and/or system apps. How do you make an APK file to an "flashable zip"?